# Ffmpeg Command Not executing with Java RunTime Command on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, ffmpeg, screen, recording

I am facing an issue regarding ffmpeg command execution in a Java Application on Mac OS.
Below is the command ::
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -r 3 -fpsprobesize 1 -i "0:0" -ar 44100 -filter_complex amix=inputs=1 -c:v h264 -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -ar 44100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -aq 1 file.mp4

When I run this command on terminal, it is working fine but with ProcessBuilder is returns
Video Device Not Found and Input/Output Error.

Please help me to understand the reason behid it.

Answer (score 0):

After changing "0:0" to 0:0, it is working fine.

ffmpeg -f avfoundation -r 3 -fpsprobesize 1 -i 0:0 -ar 44100 -filter_complex amix=inputs=1 -c:v h264 -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -ar 44100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -aq 1 file.mp4